# Heine-Borel property

Tags: real-analysis

Show directly that the interval $[0, \infty)$ does not have the Heine-Borel property.

**My attempt:**

Let $U=\{(n-1,\ n+1)\ |\ n=0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$

$U$ is an open cover of $[0, \infty)$.

How do I prove that $U$ cannot be reduced to a finite subcover?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $C\subset U$ is a finite subset of $U$; we want to show that $C$ is not a cover of $[0, \infty)$. That is, we want to find some $x\in [0, \infty)$ such that $x\not\in \bigcup C$.

We have $C=\{(n_i-1, n_i+1): i\in \{1, . . . , k\}\}$ for some $k$ (specifically $k=\vert C\vert$) and some numbers $n_i$. What can you say about the number $$n_1+n_2+...+n_k+2?$$

Comment: It does not belong to any of the elements of $C$. Could we also have used $(\max {n_i})+1$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $U_n:=(n-1,n+1)$. Then $[0,+\infty)\subseteq \cup_{n=0}^{\infty}U_n =\tilde U$. Suppose by contradiction that there exist $U_{i_0},\ldots,U_{i_N}\in U$ such that
$$[0,+\infty)\subseteq \bigcup_{n=0}^NU_{i_n}$$
so that 
$$\sup\left ([0,+\infty) \right)\le \sup \left (\bigcup_{n=0}^NU_{i_n}\right )$$
Clearly, this leads to a contradiction, since 
$$\sup \left (\bigcup_{n=0}^NU_{i_n}\right )=\max\{i_1,\ldots, i_N\}+1$$
is finite.